# json and rails 3 http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, security

Having a page which contains list of users of my site in json format .I am using jquery getJson to get the dat from that url but I need these page not to be accessible if the user tried to open it by http request.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to allow only ajax requests on your controller? (getJSON use XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I meant that I want only to allow ajax requests to that url not http request ...sorry I am newbie to ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a specific action using `request.xhr?` that checks the value of `header[X-Requested-With]` of the request.

```
def your_action
   unless request.xhr?
      render status: 404 # or what you want
      return  
   end

   # action code
end
```